# Fade out table row and contents (on scroll) in ratio to how much the row is hidden by containing div

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I'm not sure how practical this is, what the performance consequences will be or if the scroll event will fire enough for this to even work, however I have a fixed height div (`overflow-y: auto`) which contains a table.

I'd like to add an effect which fades out each row and contents (in ratio to how far it's off the screen).

The guts of the jQuery I've come up with is as follows:

```
 // on scroll event  
 $("#someDiv").on('scroll', function () {

     // get each row
     $('tr', this).each(function () {

         var mainHeight = $("#someDiv").height();
         var rowTop = $(this).offset().top;
         var rowHeight = $(this).height();
         var rowBottom = rowTop + rowHeight;


         // the row is fully off the screen
         if (rowBottom < 0 || rowTop > mainHeight) {
             $(this).css({
                 opacity: 0
             });
             return;
         }

         // the row is fully visible
         if (rowTop > 0 && rowBottom < mainHeight) {
             $(this).css({
                 opacity: 1
             });
             return;
         }

         // fade out, in ratio
         if (rowTop < 0) 
             $(this).css({opacity: rowBottom / rowHeight});
         else if (rowBottom > mainHeight) 
             $(this).css({opacity: (mainHeight - top) / height });

     });
 });
```

Though regardless of whether this code actually works, I can't get a tr to adhere to the opacity css command.

*Note: I only really need this to work in Chrome*.

Example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4PwW/)

Comment: hrm strange it seems like the tr fade is working, just not the bottom fade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems i had a few conceptual problems with the code i had

- I needed to take the containing divs top into consideration
- had various variable errors, i.e top = rowTop

the following code now works, however it is a bit slow, i might make the another question.

```
$("#someDiv").on('scroll', function () {
    var mainHeight = $(this).height();
    var mainTop = $(this).offset().top;
    $('tr', this).each(function () {

        var $this = $(this);
        var rowTop = $this.offset().top - mainTop;
        var rowHeight = $this.height();
        var rowBottom = rowTop + rowHeight;


        // the row is fully off the screen
        if (rowBottom < 0 || rowTop > mainHeight) {
            return;
        }

        // the row is fully visible
        if (rowTop >= 0 && rowBottom <= mainHeight) {
            $this.css({
                opacity: 1
            });
            return;
        }

        // fade out, in ratio
        if (rowTop < 0) 
            $this.css({ opacity: rowBottom / rowHeight});
        else if (rowBottom > mainHeight) 
            $this.css({ opacity: (mainHeight - rowTop) / rowHeight});

    });
});
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6RTYk/)**